# What causes 'error:1408D172:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_KEY_EXCHANGE:wrong signature type' SSL error?

Tags: php, ssl, curl, soap, openssl

I get the following output from CURL when attempting to fetch a WSDL from a SOAP web service on the command line (this is being used to test basic connectivity).

Server specific info has been redacted because it belongs to a vendor. The vendor say they have not had any similar reports from other users.

```
curl -v WEB-SERVICE-URL                                                                     Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
Trying WEB-SERVICE-HOST-IP...
Connected to WEB-SERVICE-HOST-NAME (WEB-SERVICE-HOST-IP) port 443 (#0)
successfully set certificate verify locations:
CAfile: none
CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
SSLv3, TLS alert, Server hello (2):
error:1408D172:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_KEY_EXCHANGE:wrong signature type
Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:1408D172:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_KEY_EXCHANGE:wrong signature type
```

I am running this command from a Ubuntu 14.04 box, curl and openssl version info below.

```
curl 7.35.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.35.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1f zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3
    pop3s rtmp rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP
```

The error appears to be fairly obscure, googling it finds very few results.

The curl command works on Ubuntu 14.04 if I specify the the `--tlsv1.1` option, so the problem appears to be TLSv1.2 specific (It also works on Ubuntu 13.04 without that option because it defaults to TLSv1.1).

I have also tested accessing the WSDL through SoapUI and this works on Ubuntu 14.04, I guess this works because SoapUI is Java and isn't using Openssl?.  Because of that and TLSv1.1 working I don't believe the issue is caused by firewalls or proxies.

TLSv1.2 also seems to be the default for the PHP SoapClient, when loading it with the WSDL I am getting `failed to load external entity` errors which I assume are caused by the same problem as the curl call.

If I could find a way to force SoapClient to use TLSv1.1 then that would be a valid work around, however it appears you can only do this by creating a stream context with specific ciphers enabled, I have attempted this but with no luck so far.

The other alternatives are to implement a Soap integration that either avoids Openssl, or allows me to specify the TLS version.

Since 14.04 is an LTS I would expect this work and if the problem is with Openssl I would like to get to the bottom of it, anybody have any ideas?.

---

**Edit**

Using s_client I get slightly more information in the error message.

`139860433102496:error:1408D172:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_KEY_EXCHANGE:wrong signature type:s3_clnt.c:1765:`

This indicates the error is being thrown [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/ssl/s3_clnt.c#L1765) in the openssl code.

---

**Edit 2**

The Cipher used (successfully) by SoapUI is
     TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA`, looking at the result of`openssl ciphers

I can't see the equivalent cipher.

---

**Edit 3**

The following command `openssl s_client -tls1_2 -cipher DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA -prexit -connect` produces output which ends with the following.

```
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
Protocol  : TLSv1.2
Cipher    : 0000
Session-ID: 3ED4F6AB3EAD9BAD50059F9881951D2A759DC10FA1108B3107EA3374CC4922EE
Session-ID-ctx: 
Master-Key: 
Key-Arg   : None
PSK identity: None
PSK identity hint: None
SRP username: None
Start Time: 1430373464
Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

Comment: It's a strange error but somebody saw these errors with some Java implementation on the server side, see https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/tls/current/msg15961.html. It would be good to know the real URL to check if this is the same kind of problem or something different.

Comment: And I assume the difference between OpenSSL with various TLS versions and the SOAP UI is the choice of ciphers used.  The referenced problems about wrong encoding of ServerDHParams should happen only with specific ciphers and the choosen cipher also depends on client capbilities and TLS version.

Comment: I'll ask the vendor but I am not sure how helpful it would be as it won't be accessible publicly.  I have added some more info about the error and ciphers, based on your comments I am beginning to think that SoapUI's TLS implementation knows about a cipher that OpenSSL doesn't, is that likely?.

Comment: OpenSSL has usually more ciphers implemented than Java, but uses a different naming scheme : `TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` is there called `DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA` (both are cipher code `0x00,0x33`).  And since your problem only happens with TLS1.2 I assume that one of the new ciphers in TLS1.2 is the problem (check `openssl ciphers -V | grep TLSv1.2`)  and the cipher used by the Java UI is not a new TLS1.2 cipher.

Comment: It would be helpful for debugging if you could make a packet capture so that one can have a look into the details of the handshake with wireshark. You should also be able to work around the problem by restricting the ciphers used, e.g. `--cipher DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA` with curl, `-cipher DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA` with s_client and  also [somehow with PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php).

Comment: And the line relevant to the error is probably more [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_1f/ssl/s3_clnt.c#L1733) (use tag OpenSSL_1_0_1f and look for the error). The code indicates that it is can only happen with TLS1.2.

Comment: Ah, in that case I suspect SoapUI is using TLS 1.1, which probably means the vendors servers TLS 1.2 implementation is at fault.

Comment: Yes, I suspect this too and if one could make a packet capture one could maybe prove it too.

Comment: Yup, using wireshark I can see that SoapUI uses TLSv1.0. Thanks for all your help. There is still something here I don't understand though, I can only get curl to work on Ubuntu 14.04 by specifying the ````--tlsv1.1```` option, if I specify the cipher as you suggested (````curl -v --cipher DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA````) I get the same ````wrong signature type```` error, likewise with the cipher specified in the PHP stream context I still can't connect.

Comment: Then it is probably not related to the cipher but to a wrong implementation of TLS1.2 on the server side. I would be interested to have a look at the pcap of the failed connection to see exactly what went wrong.

Comment: Steffen, thanks for all your help.  I have contacted the vendor suggesting that the problem is with their TLSv1.2 implementation and am now awaiting a response.  If you want to put together an answer that says the same thing I will happily accept it, or we can wait to find out what the vendor says.  In any case I will update this question when I have a resolution.

Comment: @Andrew - Please post the exact URL you are using to connect to the server, and post the output of `openssl s_client -connect <hostname>:<port> -tls1 -servername <hostname> -debug`. If you don't want to share vendor and server information, then you should open a support ticket with the vendor. We will also have to move to close this as "unable to duplicate" because you won't provide the required information.

Comment: @jww Feel free to close, I have not heard back from the vendor yet, but TLSv1.2 has suddenly started working this morning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering just for completeness, TLSv1.2 started working the next day after I raised it with the vendor, they later confirmed it was server side problem.